# Header JSON Converting CSV to JSON

Tags: c#, choetl

Hi im tring to convert CSV String to JSON, but the Header of the JSON has some issues with Encode i think.

Here the code and the Output:

> [{...
>       "Endere_o_4": "",
>         "Endere_o_5": "",
>         "Endere_o_6": "",
>         "C_digo_Postal": "1000-045", ...]}

> Expected Result: [{...
>       "Endereço_4": "",
>         "Endereço_5": "",
>         "Endereço_6": "",
>         "Código_Postal": "1000-045", ...]}

```
public void MssCSVtoJSON(string ssCSV, out string ssJSON)
        {
            ssJSON = "";

            ChoCSVFileHeaderConfiguration headerConfiguration = new ChoCSVFileHeaderConfiguration(null, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-PT"));
            ChoCSVRecordConfiguration config = new ChoCSVRecordConfiguration();
            config.FileHeaderConfiguration = headerConfiguration;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (var p = ChoCSVReader.LoadText(ssCSV,Encoding.Unicode, config, null).WithFirstLineHeader())  {
                using (var w = new ChoJSONWriter(sb))   {
                    w.Configuration.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
                    w.Write(p);
                }
            }
            ssJSON = sb.ToString();
            // TODO: Write implementation for action
        } // MssCSVtoJSON
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is known issue, put a fix and pushed `ChoETL 1.1.0.5-alpha2` nuget package.

Here is working sample

```
string csv = @"Endereço_4, Endereço_5
1, 11
2, 22";
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
using (var r = ChoCSVReader.LoadText(csv).WithFirstLineHeader())
{
    using (var w = new ChoJSONWriter(output))
        w.Write(r);
}

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

**Output:**

```
[
 {
  "Endereço_4": "1",
  "Endereço_5": "11"
 },
 {
  "Endereço_4": "2",
  "Endereço_5": "22"
 }
]
```